# Dart: Parse JSON with comments

Tags: json, dart, parsing, comments

I already tried to filter them out before parsing, but the Problem is, that it is possible to have "//", "/*" and "*/" inside a value, for example if the value is a link or something.

An example:

```
{
     /*
          this is an explanation for something
     */
     "linkToSomething": "https://something.net" // this is a link to something
     
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's also [JSON5](https://json5.org/) which supports single and multi-line comments. Looks like the [json5](https://pub.dev/packages/json5) package on pub.dev is what you're looking for. :)

Here's an example on how to use it:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:json5/json5.dart';

void main(List<String> arguments) async {
  // Read the file which contains the JSON.
  final value = await File('<file>').readAsString();
  
  // Parse it using the json5 package instead of dart:convert.
  final parsed = json5Decode(value);
}
```

Comment: This kinda works for me, the only problem is, that it cant parse any "\r\n". the way i solved this is, that i first replaced all "\r\n" with "endl" and afterwards replaced it back to "\r\n". This solution however can couse Problems in the future. For know, I will just leave it as is and open an Issue on GitHub at JSON5 package and hope it gets solved. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

It's technically possible to remove comments using a `RegExp`, you just have to detect string literals too, to avoid triggering on comments inside strings, and then not remove the strings, only the comments. Strings are slightly tricky because of escapes, but at least JSON only uses one kind of quote.

```dart
var commentRE = RegExp(r'"(?:[^\\"]|\\[^])*"|/\*[^]*?\*/|//.*');
String removeComments(String jsonWithComments) => 
   jsonWithComments.replaceAllMapped(commentRE, (m) {
      var s = m[0]!;
      return s.startsWith('"') ? s : "";
   });
```

I'm assuming no *nested* comments because that makes detecting them non-regular.